# Сделать приоритет для маски телефона используя jquery.inputmask

Tags: javascript, jquery

Для телефона написал такую маску:

```
$("#phone").inputmask("(8 999 999 99 99)|(+7 999 999 99 99)|(+7 99999 9 99 99)|(8 99999 9 99 99)|(+7 9999 99 99 99)|(8 9999 99 99 99)");
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы именно первая маска (мобильного телефона) была в приоритете и подставлялась первой при заполнении поля?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что автор нашел решение (см. удаленный ответ, если достаточно репутации), никому о нем не сказал и свалил.

Comment: Может в этом случае имеет смысл дать ответ на поставленный вопрос?! С подобным вопросом могут и другие столкнуться в будущем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самым гибким вариантом будет для вас, повесить слушатель события keyup и менять маски в зависимости от введенного значения. Приведу пример смены маски для номеров с 8 или +7. При таком подходе вы сможете полностью контролировать приоритет маск и кейсы их применения относительно введенного значения.

```js
let $phone = $('#phone');
//Маска по умолчанию
$phone.inputmask("9 999 9999-999");

$phone.on("keyup", function(event) {
  //Получаем значение поле без маски
  var value = $(event.target).inputmask("unmaskedvalue");

  //Далее могут быть любые проверки, чтобы изменить маску на нужную..
  //Например:сделаем для номеров +7
  if (value.length === 2 && value === "+7") {
    $phone.inputmask("+7 (999) 999-99-99");
  }
  //Если поле очистили, уберем маску и значение, можем еще вернуть маску по умолчанию при необходимости
  if (value === "") $phone.inputmask('remove').val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<label for="phone">Номер</label>
<input type="text" id="phone" />
```